# Are there nouns for being secondary/tertiary/etc. like "primacy"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm just wondering, as I've used primacy quite a lot but have never thought of other words like it.

Comment: *tertiarity* is rare and may not be in a dictionary, but a google search reveals it exists.

Comment: Not my favourite word, but [the full OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/174505) has an entry for **secondariness** - *The quality of being secondary or subordinate.*

Comment: They often appear as nouns when the actual noun has been dropped to avoid tedious repetition. *The secondary* is a term from American football, so it is known by everyone and that probably helps with this sort of extension. Also, it would be widely known as a term for a bomb set to explode after the primary has gone off (thanks to *The Hurt Locker*).

Comment: sometimes "runner-up" can be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Primary. Probably a better choice than *primacy*, which is a noun and usually carries the meaning of first in importance.
2. Secondary
3. Tertiary
4. [Quaternary](http://www.fossils-facts-and-finds.com/quaternary_period.html) From the website fossil-facts-and-finds.com:

   > In the early 1800’s a system for naming geologic time periods was
   >   devised using four periods of geologic time.... Early geologists chose
   >   the name **Quaternary** for the fourth period in this system. We no
   >   longer use this system of dividing geologic time, but the name,
   >   **Quaternary**, is still commonly used for the most recent period in geologic time.
5. [Quinary](https://books.google.com/books?id=jGiL8zkqnCQC&pg=PT119&dq=%22quinary%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja8fb3waDNAhXCFR4KHTqUCl44ChDoAQgvMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22quinary%22&f=false). From *The Mystery of Numbers* by A Schimmel:

   > The tendency to group things in **quinary** arrangements is
   >   omnipresent. Among such groups, the 5 senses certainly have to do with
   >   5 as the number of natural man,....
6. [Senary](https://books.google.com/books?id=FXUIAQAAMAAJ&q=%22senary%22&dq=%22senary%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJivj5wqDNAhUGJx4KHQTGDkYQ6AEIMzAF). From *German music theory in the early 17th century* by B V Rivera:

   > He extols the **senary** by pointing out how nature and art manifest
   >   countless states of perfection through "sixness."
7. [Septenary](https://books.google.com/books?id=zAnjAbsgY0gC&pg=PA3&dq=%22septenary%22%20%20seven&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy_sSuyKDNAhWHsh4KHfzmAMgQ6AEIKjAD#v=onepage&q=%22septenary%22%20%20seven&f=false). From *Invitation to Italian Poetry* by L Rebay:

   > To be sure, Italian poets have made frequent use of other regular
   >   meters, particularly the **septenary** (seven-syllable line),....
8. [Octonary](https://books.google.com/books?id=o_fuAAAAMAAJ&q=%22octonary%22&dq=%22octonary%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8tt2cyaDNAhWCWh4KHb3GBLcQ6AEIMDAE). From *History of binary and other nondecimal numeration* by A Glaser:

   > He came to the conclusion that the "**octonary**" (base 8) scale would 
   >   be the best possible one.
9. [Nonary](https://books.google.com/books?id=jR6xIqUANywC&pg=PA27&dq=%22nonary%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ1P28yaDNAhVFHh4KHcLbAXQQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22nonary%22&f=false). From *Mysteries and Secrets of Numerology* by L Fanthorpe and P Fanthorpe:

   > For example, because “9” has certain peculiarities, what is called a
   >   **nonary** system, or base-9, may be employed for some numerological processes.
10. [Denary](https://books.google.com/books?id=iwUOAQAAMAAJ&q=%22denary%22&dq=%22denary%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizxsigyqDNAhUDXR4KHbwaDW8Q6AEIQDAH). From *The great encounter of China and the West, 1500-1800* by D E Mungello:

    > Leibniz had developed a binary system of arithmetic, which, unlike the
    >   commonly used **denary** system of today that relies upon ten digits
    >   (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9), generated all arithmetical
    >   calculations using only two numbers (0 and 1).
11. [Undenary](http://www.chessvariants.com/large.dir/undenary.html). From the website Undenary Chess by M A Rouse:

    > **Undenary** Chess is a large chess variant for two persons.... The board is made up of 121 [i.e., 11x11] alternating light and dark
    >   squares, with a light-colored square at each corner and the very
    >   center of the board.
12. [Duodenary](https://books.google.com/books?id=b8IYAAAAIAAJ&q=%22duodenary%22&dq=%22duodenary%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFisaXy6DNAhXEWx4KHe4LBqAQ6AEIPTAH). From *The philosophy of Leibniz: metaphysics and language* by B Mates:

    > If we understand by a ternary, a senary, and a **duodenary**, numbers
    >   divisible by 3, 6, and 12, respectively, then we can demonstrate this
    >   proposition: every duodenary is a senary....

​2​0. Vicenary or vigenary. From the *OED* quoting *The Penny Cyclopedia II* (1834)

> In France, the scale from 60 to 100 is strictly **vicenary** (by twenties)